# Article before mass noun

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, difference, nouns, indefinite-article

By the rules we don't place an indefinite article before a mass noun but I've heard both usages:

1. What a good weather we have today!
2. What good weather we have today!

Is there a difference between them and are they actually both correct?

P.s. I always prefer the first one, although everybody says it's incorrect. It reads easier and faster and sounds better than without the indefinite article.

Comment: For some reason, I always prefer the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the noun is not normally used in the plural (e.g. ~weathers, ~Englishes) then you will find the indefinite article only in the rarest of circumstances, in which the speaker is presenting the singularity as a multiplicity, the underlying idea being that of *variety*:

> She speaks **an** impeccable English.
>
> The island has **a** weather like none you've ever experienced.

A variety of English, a variety of weather.

But in typical conversation, we'd tend to say:

> She speaks impeccable English.
>
> The island has weather like  you've never experienced.

Comment: Why then can we say, "**A good knowledge of English**" or "**He has an amazing intuition**". Bith these nouns are not used in the plural and they are also uncountable nouns. But I doubt the idea here is **variety**.

Comment: @SovereignSun: The idea here is indeed variety, in a minimalist sense: knowledge is divided into two sorts: good and not good. "A good knowledge" is much like "an impeccable English".